# Error 404 GitPages

Tags: javascript, html

Hola al generar una nueva pagina en gitHub pages me arroja error 404
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo en el codigo lo tengo definido de la siguiente manera

```
    function Generar() {
    let parms = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(ElForm)).toString();
    location.href = '/firma.html?' + parms; //<<descomentar esto

}
```

Estará el problema en como defino la nueva pagina?

Comment: Es el "/" que va primero. Tienes que colocar tu ruta entera -> location.href = '/algo_aca/otracosapuedeser/y_asi/cuantas_carptetas/tengas/firma.html?' + parms

Comment: nuevamente muchas gracias yussef ya lo arregle.